# Image Binding Not Working on Reload Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an Image element that's bound to an ImageSource element inside a class that I've created.  The ImageSource gets updated every time a slider is changed.  When I first instantiate my window, the ImageSource is blank until the user loads a file.  Once the file is loaded, the image appears and the user can scroll the slider and see the image change.  They can then select "OK" on the dialog to save this pattern.  This all works fine.

However, if they double-click on the item in the ListView then it will re-open this dialog to make further edits. So, it creates a new dialog and then reloads the pertinent info about the image.  However, for whatever reason... the image binding no longer works.  I can put a breakpoint on the ImageSource getter and everytime I change the slider, the image does get updated... However, it just doesn't appear the be binding correctly.  Why would it bind correctly on the first time the window is opened, but not on subsequent openings.  I'll try to lay out my code.

In my .XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.CreatePattern"
             x:Name="PatternCreation"
             ...
             d:DesignHeight="160" d:DesignWidth="350">

    <Slider Value="{Binding ElementName=PatternCreation, Path=Pattern.ZNorm, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="1" Name="Slider" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Image Name="PatternPreview" Source="{Binding ElementName=PatternCreation, Path=Pattern.WPFSlice}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
</UserControl
```

In my code behind I define the Pattern to be bound:

```
protected PatternVoxelBased mPattern = new PatternVoxelBased();
public PatternVoxelBased Pattern
{
    get { return mPattern ; }
    set { mPattern = value; }
}
```

In my PatternVoxelBased class, I have a WPFSlice and ZNorm properties defined like this:

```
protected ImageSource mWPFSlice;
public ImageSource WPFSlice
{
    get { return mWPFSlice; }
    set
    {
        mWPFSlice = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("WPFSlice");
    }
}

protected double mZNorm = 0.5;
public double ZNorm
{
    get { return mZNorm; }
    set
    {
        if (mZNorm == value) return;
        mZNorm = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ZNorm");
        WPFSlice = BuildImageAtZ(mZNorm);
    }
}
```

I have an event to load the dialog window the first time:

```
private void CreatePattern_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CCreateVoxelPattern dlg = new CCreateVoxelPattern();
    dlg.DataContext = DataContext;
    dlg.CShow(PatternLibraryMenu);
}
```

My ListView Double-Click function to reload the dialog window:

```
private void ListViewPatternLibrary_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    PatternVoxelBased item = ((ListView)sender).SelectedValue as PatternVoxelBased;
    CCreateVoxelPattern dlg = new CCreateVoxelPattern();
    dlg.DataContext = DataContext;
    dlg.Main.Pattern = item;
    dlg.Main.LoadPattern();  
    dlg.CShow(PatternLibraryMenu);
}

public void LoadPattern()
{
    if (Pattern == null) return;
    Pattern.WPFSlice = Pattern.BuildImageAtZ(Pattern.ZNorm);
 }
```

Comment: Your implementation for `INotifyPropertyChanged` is missing...

Comment: Do you mean for the setter in the Pattern property? Or for the WPFSlice? Because it is in the WPFSlice (I just didn't put it in the original code).  I'll edit the post.  I don't think I can add a INotifyPropertyChanged to my code behind (where I define the Pattern property) because it violates the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class where this is

```
protected PatternVoxelBased mPattern = new PatternVoxelBased();
public PatternVoxelBased Pattern
{
    get { return mPattern ; }
    set { mPattern = value; }
}
```

you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Example**

```
public class YourClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
   {
      PropertyChanged(this, e);
   }
}

protected PatternVoxelBased mPattern = new PatternVoxelBased();
public PatternVoxelBased Pattern
{
    get { return mPattern ; }
    set { mPattern = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Pattern"));}
}
}
```

**EDIT**

In your `Pattern`-class, you have to implement that too on every Property.

Comment: I can't seem to add the inheritance to INotifyPropertyChanged for that class.  This is in the code-behind my .xaml.  So, my class structure looks like this:  public partial class CreatePattern: UserControl
    { ....  }

Comment: Also... The Image properly displays the correct the ImageSource the first time the dialog is opened (without adding the INotifyPropertyChanged inheritance you mentioned.  It's upon reloading the dialog that the Image fails to bind properly.

Comment: Yes, but it only shows one time, and then the binding gets never noticed about any change